# Почему не выводит текст в консоль?

Tags: c#, async-await

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       test();

    }

        public async static void test(){
            var result = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {        
             Thread.Sleep(1000);
             return "Результат обработки";
           });
           Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что программа успевает завершиться пока задача спит.

Фоновые задачи не продляют время работы программы.